# Is there a standard message type for waypoint in 3D space?

Tags: ros, uav, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Going to add a control in the flight plan mavros.
Is there a standard message / ROS API for managing waypoint?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132221/is-there-a-standard-message-type-for-waypoint-in-3d-space?/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2014-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does [nav_msgs/Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) have what you want?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2014-02-23**:
In APM we have several types of waypoints with additional parameters and in global or local frame (coordinates).
And it dosen't use orientation (only coordinates).

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-24**:
You could just ignore the orientation of the path? If you have special custom parameters you probably wont find them in a standard message? @dan-lazewatsky: that should be "Path", not "Plan" ;)

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2014-02-24**:
Thanks, I decided to use custom message type for waypoints.
And extra node for translation to geographic_msgs/WayPoint (if it really needed).